# why the browser based solidity compiler crushes when the code is too long?

Tags: solidity, remix

I find that the browser based solidity compiler will crush when the code's length reach certain value which is about 230 lines. I don't know why and I am certain that there is no syntax mistake, does this problem ever happen to you?

Answer (score 4):

Compiling code takes a lot of computing power, especially when you recompile every time you edit. There's simply a limit to how much you can do within a browser.

If you're writing a lot of code, I would highly reccomend utilizing a framework or command-line compiler

Comment: you mean the mix?

Comment: when I deploy it using the mist, the mist also crushes

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried in CLI environment?

```
solc --bin --abi yourcode.sol
```

and check the result first.

--- install CLI Ethereum 
In case of MIST,
they already have geth 
I think 230 lines code is not a problem.
Because there's more than 230 code is existing.
So, first you try compile in command line.

you can download CLI ethereum package 
https://build.ethereum.org/cpp-binaries-data/release-1.2.2/Ethereum.exe

Comment: the only way I can to deploy the contract is using mist, can you teach me how to do this?

Comment: I think 230 lines code is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Javascript `solc` was automatically generated from c++ code which makes it wildly inefficient.*

The `solc` compiler is **extremely slow**. A few hundred lines will begin to take over a minute to compile. For comparison, the `solc` package included in [cpp-ethereum](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/index.html#what-are-the-primary-executables) takes about 1 second.

I believe that the Javascript `solc` package was actually automatically generated from the `solc` implementation in c++ (possibly using something like [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/03/cpp-to-javascript)). You can actually view the JS source [here](https://github.com/ethereum/browser-solidity/blob/gh-pages/bin/soljson-latest.js). As you can see, the JS compiler is insanely complex and likely extremely inefficient. If you are a compiler guru it would be a great service the community if you would rewrite this JS compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ethereum Studio on [live.ether.camp](https://live.ether.camp) 
as a full functional web based dev environment it 
should support all your requirements.